I am integrating the Samsung health step count functionality, but permission is not turning on
I took a partner program with Samsung health in my application, i integrated the code to fetch the step count data after integration of the permission code as per the developer guide defined in the Samsung's documentation.
Permission popup came as defined in the guide. But when i try to make it enable the switch is not working, Is there anything specific that i need to do for that or something else.
Any help will be great for me.. Thanks.
I tried checking the demo code of the step diary created by Samsung guide and checked all the necessary code as per the demo application. Everything looks good.
